Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
When i run the code in flutter run the error will occurs. recently i changed tthe gradle properties file. 7 version to 8 verison.
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/firebase_auth/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/firebase_core/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/flutter_local_notifications/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/url_launcher_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/path_provider_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/google_sign_in_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:/Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/connectivity_plus/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/firebase_auth/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/firebase_core/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :flutter_local_notifications) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/flutter_local_notifications/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :url_launcher_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/url_launcher_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/path_provider_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :google_sign_in_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/google_sign_in_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :connectivity_plus) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/build/connectivity_plus/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

app/gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.fitish_app"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    //for notification
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }

    compileOptions {

         //for notification
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fitish_app"
        multiDexEnabled true
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    //for notification
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'

}

gradle.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

How to fix this.
Try to fix this in flutter .this app succussfully working in the ios errror occurs in android only .
what the error. why its occur

Issue in this dependency ----> implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
Just add the latest kotlin version instead the "+" and sync and after sync just
rebuild the gradle issue is solve.
solution:
from
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
to:
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1" update the dependency.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
